# Fill 4 bytes little endian with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, endianness

How can I convert number to 4 bytes little endian with python?

For example : `1 -> 01000000` and `258 -> 02010000`

Comment: do you have any code example? or do you expect someone code it for you? please check [ask]

Answer (score 4):

Try with struct, 'this module performs conversions between Python values and C structs represented as Python strings':

```
import struct
print(struct.pack('<i', 258))
```

where < mean little-endian and i that the element to be pack is an integer

Output:

```
b'\x02\x01\x00\x00'
```

Comment: But if this code will run at 64 bits machine this will be 8 bytes.   Is there any way to limit that explicit to 4 byte?

Comment: The code is running in a 64 bits machine and the result is as shown, if you want to know more about it please refer to: https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html @ttx32063Eoopy.com